# When i press on tag <a> can i send information to anoth

Tags: javascript, asp.net

this is the code

```
<a onclick='function()'> <img  src="images/img.jpg" /></a>
```

and when i press him change the page and send a information like a string

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the document location in the function that will be called in the click, and send something in the query string to the other page:

```
<a onclick='theClick()'> <img  src="images/img.jpg" /></a>

function theClick()
{
   document.location = "anotherpage.aspx?data=thedatevalue";
}
```

Comment: While this will work, it's generally not going to be a best practice. `<a>` tags are for actual links, so why over-complicate it by calling a Javascript function just to handle navigating to another page? Just point the `href` attribute to where you want to go. Secondly, some users explicitly disable Javascript in their browsers, which would cause this solution to not even be viable.

Comment: I agree that using href will be a better practice, I actually saw you posted your answer before me, however I wanted to response more specifically  the original question, also even that is possible to disable JS, doing it now days it will practically disable the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider just using a normal link and setting the data that you wanted to pass as querystring parameters :

```
<a href='YourOtherPage.aspx?key=value'>
    <img src="images/img.jpg" />
</a>
```

Then you could simply access your values via the `Request` object within the `Page_Load` event of your other page :

```
// Retrieve your value (this will match the name of your key and contain the value)
var key = Request["key"];
```

Comment: and how can i send a variable to the destiny page?

Comment: The `href` property of your `<a>` tag will take care of that. Querystring parameters use the format `{page-name}.aspx?{key}={value}&{another-key}={another-value}`. So if your page was called "Destiny.aspx", you would just need to point the `href` attribute to that along with your parameters.